# Resize Mac Partition is Disabled - how to partition properly

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have two partitions on my mac book pro. One partition is running os Yosemite and other one is running bootcamp windows 8.1. Yosemite is 75GB and Bootcamp has 673GB. I shrinked the windows partition by and made 142 GB available, but that space is not available to the mac side and neither can I see it from Disk Utility. What is the proper way to increase my macintosh HD without loosing any data? I am not able to resize any partitions from the mac side.

[image]

diskutil list output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apple's tools won't shrink the Bootcamp partition, so you have several options:

- get a third party tool to back up Bootcamp and/or shrink it outright
- install OS X on an external drive and run it there (basically punt)

There's a slight chance you have a siruation that could be remedied from he command line. Post the `diskutil list` details that Disk Utility doesn't show by default. Also, can you lose no data on Windows side? If you could delete that partition the side Mac could resize without any data loss.

See:

- [Unable to increase partition size with subsequent blocking partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130862/unable-to-increase-partition-size-with-subsequent-blocking-partition)
- [OS X Partition not resizable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148645/os-x-partition-not-resizable)
- [Resizing dual boot partitions in Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153523/resizing-dual-boot-partitions-in-yosemite)

Comment: I booted into windows and shrinked the bootcamp HD, but that doesn't show any difference when loading into Yosemite again. I have updated my question with a screenshot of the output for the diskutil list command. I can't loose data from my windows partition. If there is really no option, then I will do it, but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: @skone great detail. You are in a "pickle" - shrinking disk0s4 would free space for adding a disk0s5. You can't shuffle space up the chain, so you'll need to use a tool like gparted which is linked in my See: section.

Comment: I shrinked disk0s4 from the windows side, but its not visible from the mac side. I guess I need to do that using [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php)?

Comment: Shrinking the disk in Windows subtracts space from the *end* of the partition (the bottom of the BOOTCAMP area on your screencap) for Disk Utility to be able to expand the Mac partition into the available space you would have to shrink it from the beginning of the partition. Windows can't do that. GPartEd *might* be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @SteveChambers that makes sense. I will try to use GPartEd